# select options are not dispalying in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to show the dropdown list with options in it but they are not displaying. I am getting the data in the controller. but not in html

Below is the code

in HTML

```
<select name="nameSelect" id="nameSelect" ng-model="model.name">
        <option ng-repeat="option1 in names" value="{{option1}}">{{option1}}</option>
      </select>
```

In controller

```
$scope.init = function () {
      var url = "/someurl";
      $http.get(url)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data[0].name.firstname); //Object {0: "name1", 1: "name2"}
          $scope.names = response.data[0].name.firstname;
        });
    };
```

In the above controller I can see the data by console.log.

```
Object {0: "name1", 1: "name2"}.
```

In db
        "firstname" : {
            "0" : "name1",
            "1" : "name2"
        }

How can I set the values in select box in angularjs.

Comment: option1 in name.name=> what is name.name. I don't see it in your controller.

Comment: it is names I have edit the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, you are trying to loop an Object,

```
  <select name="nameSelect" id="nameSelect" ng-model="model.name">
            <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in names" value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
     </select>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vedp/2u8t11um/1/

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<select name="nameSelect" id="nameSelect" ng-model="model.name">
  <option value="">-Select Name-</option>
  <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in names" value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```